# why does os.system("source /home/oracle/.bash_profile") not work

Tags: python

```
[root@izm5e8t6lxkk4uk1hn5639z ~]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("source /home/oracle/.bash_profile")
0
>>> os.system("echo $PATH")
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
0
>>>
```

why PATH does not change ? what the 0 MEANS

Comment: use `os.popen()` and for path you can use `glob` module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `os.system` spawns a shell, that sets it's own path with your `source` command and then immediately exits. You could set the path and then immediately run the program:

```
os.system("source /home/oracle/.bash_profile && your_command_here")
```

Though I would caution you, this is not the recommended way to run external programs. Using `subprocess` is a better idea, as is avoiding spawning shells (subprocess helps you in that area)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess